# Animating Width of Flexbox Parent Doesn't Affect Children?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, gsap

I'm trying to use TweenLite to tween in the width of the blue sidebar down to zero. Unfortunately, the content of the blue sidebar breaks outside of the bounds of the parent.

[image]

This is something that really should never happen with Flexbox, but the child elements are also Flex containers so I'm sure what I'm doing wrong here. :( If anyone has any suggestions please let me know. Thanks!

Here a link tot he live demo: https://jimtheman.github.io/Flexbox-Push-Drawer-Example/#/
And here you can read the source code: https://github.com/JimTheMan/Flexbox-Push-Drawer-Example/tree/gh-pages

ps. Id like to get this working, but I'm wordering if there is a way to get the center green piece to stretch to fill the container as the blue column shrinks without using Flexbox.

Comment: `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: You have loads of different `widths` specified and applied throughout your example on the elements. Maybe you should try to clean up your classes and design and then try again..

Comment: @Henrik because I DO want things to be different widths... Maybe try making a useful comment instead of an ignorant, snide remark.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mean to sound ignorant. I just tried sharing what my experience is, and having code that's unstructured usually gets me off track. The `#right-column` has it's width specified 5 times. `10px` (css, id), `200px` (css, id), `100%` (css, class),`100%` (css attribute) and when you click the orange column it's definied once more with an inline width. Again, no hard feelings or ignorant remarks, just trying to advice.

Comment: You mentioned "css attribute 100%", but I don't see that anywhere in the code. The first 10px can be removed. I'm sorry that was so distracting to you.

Comment: I read the different attributes through the chrome console. As I said, just trying to help.

Comment: ok I wasn't very nice either. sorry. chill vibes

Answer (score 0):

Setting `overflow:hidden` on the `.whole-app-container' element solved my problem.